# How to calculate p-value for t-test if original data is not available?

Tags: t-test, p-value

I have two (normally distributed) samples:

First: n=50 mean=3 sd=2

Second: n=40 mean=3.5 sd=1.9

Is this enough to perform two-sample and two-sided Student's t-test with equal variances? If yes, how can I compute p-value in R? Function t.test() accepts only original data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See responses on [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-to-perform-two-sample-t-tests-in-r-by-inputting-sample-statistics-rather-tha)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Just plug-and-chug these values into the t-test formula. I'm going to assume the samples are independent, and this is an unpaired two-tailed test:

$ t= \frac{\left | \bar{X_1} - \bar{X_2} \right |}{\sqrt{s_1^2 /n_1 + s_2^2 /n_2  }} $

Once you've calculated this t statistic, compare it against the appropriate t-value for the significance level you are testing for at $df = n_1 +n_2 - 2$. At $df = 88$,  $t \geq 1.99$ gives a significance of $p \leq 0.05$ (via [this](http://archive.bio.ed.ac.uk/jdeacon/statistics/table1.html#Student%27s%20t%20test) t-table). In your case, $t=1.21$, so your sample means are not significantly different at the $p=0.05$ level.

If you need to calculate the exact p-value, instead of looking it up in a t-table you can use the r function for the $t$ CDF, `pt()`, which gives $p = 0.2288375$ for your data when you specify that you want the upper tail of the distribution (`lower.tail=F`) and double your result for a two-tailed test.

Here's the whole thing wrapped in a little function in case you have more similar tests to run:

```
homebrew_two_tailed_t_test = function(m1, m2, n1, n2, s1, s2){
  t = abs(m1-m2)/sqrt(s1^2/n1 + s2^2/n2)
  2*pt(t, n1 + n2 -2, lower.tail=F)
}

>homebrew_two_tailed_t_test(3.5, 3, 50, 40, 2, 1.9)
0.2288375
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about p-value?

Comment: Reference my edited post

Comment: Sorry, I still do not see how to compute p-value. Tables for Student test are not p-values.

Comment: The table I linked you gives the reference t-value for a given p value with the degrees of freedom of your test. Check the link.

Comment: P-value is number between zero and one. No number from your answer satisfies this except p=0.05 but this is alpha, not exact p-value.

Comment: Assuming David Marx calculated the $t$-value and the $df$ correctly, `R` gives a p-value of: `pt(1.69, 88, lower.tail = FALSE)` =  `0.04728384`. Note that this is a one-sided test, so you need to multiply it by two for the two sided test which is (non-significant): `0.0946`.

Comment: FYI there was a slight miscalculation earlier in the t figure I gave: i had treated the standard deviations you provided as though they were variances. I updated my answer to give you the correct t and corresponding p values, and have also provided a small r snippet for you.